# Cassandra cluster works with 2 nodes?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-node-driver

I have 2 nodes with replication factor = 1, it means will have 1 set of data copy in each node.

Based on above description when i use murmur3partitioner,

1. Will data shared among nodes ? like 50% of data in node1 and 50% of data in node 2?
2. when i read request to node 1 , will it internally connect with node 2 for consistency ?

And my intention is to make a replica and both nodes should server the request independently without inter communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please try to ask only one question at per post.

> I have 2 nodes with replication factor = 1, it means will have 1 set of data copy in each node.

Incorrect.  A RF=1 indicates that your entire cluster will have 1 copy of the data.

> Will data shared among nodes ? like 50% of data in node1 and 50% of data in node 2?

That is what it will try to do.  Do note that it probably won't be exact.  It'll probably be something like 49/51-ish.

> when i read request to node 1 , will it internally connect with node 2 for consistency ?

With a RF=1, no it will not.  Based on the hashed token value of your partition key, it will be directed only to the node which contains the data.

As an example, with a RF=2 with 2 nodes, it would depend on the consistency level set for your operation.  Reading at ONE will always read only one replica.  Reading at QUORUM will always read from 2 replicas with 2 nodes (after all, QUORUM of 2 equals 2).  Reading at ALL will require a response from all replicas, and initiate a read repair if they do not agree.

Important to note, but you cannot force your driver to connect to a specific Cassandra node.  You may provide one endpoint, but it will find the other via gossip, and use it as it needs to.

Comment: thanks for the clear information. In case of 2 nodes with RF=2 at any case both nodes talk each other for a data request ? or it will return the data from only one node with out contacting another node at all ?

Comment: @Sathish Again, it depends on what consistency level you are querying at.  If you set your driver to query at ONE, it will only talk to one node to verify a replica.  Anything higher than that, and it will attempt to verify replicas on more than one node.